# why is my regex greedy

Tags: regex

The regex in question is:

```
(edit[\s\S]{0,}?service ("ALL")[\s\S]{0,}?next)
```

In the following example, my regex is working properly and it finds me all matches correctly from this:

```
edit 1035
    set schedule "always"
    set service "ALL"
    set utm-status enable
next
edit 103
    set schedule "always"
    set service "ALL"
    set utm-status enable
next
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/A5E8Iu/1/

However, if I change the first occurrence of `ALL` for `ALL2`:

```
edit 1035
    set schedule "always"
    set service "ALL2"
    set utm-status enable
next
edit 103
    set schedule "always"
    set service "ALL"
    set utm-status enable
next
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/A5E8Iu/2

it becomes greedy and includes the first match instead of only including the second one

Can someone explain me why it does not start at "edit 103" in the following updated example?

Comment: You have blocks of texts, and since the first block `edit` can be matched first, it is matched, and then `[\s\S]*?` matches up to the first occurrence of `service "ALL"` that is in the second block. Regex engine parses strings from left to right. You might fix it [like this, for example](https://regex101.com/r/J3X4ZE/1).

Comment: See this: https://regex101.com/r/A5E8Iu/4

Comment: Or uses `[\s\S]` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your regex is the only one that works for my case. While I don't fully understand it, I learned alot from it. Thank you !

Comment: @GuillaumeCaillé See my answer below with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a regex engine parses strings from left to right.

You have blocks of substrings that are delimited with `edit` and `next`. Since the first `edit` block can be matched first, it is matched, and then `[\s\S]*?` matches up to the first occurrence of `service "ALL"` that is in the second block.

You might fix the regex using a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
edit(?:(?!edit)[\s\S])*?service ("ALL")[\s\S]*?next
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lvws2F/1).

The `(?:(?!edit)[\s\S])*?` construct matches any char (`[\s\S]`), 0+ repetitions as few as possible (`*?`), that does not start the `edit` char sequence.

However, if `edit` or `next` happen to be inside the block, you will have incorrect matches. A safer regex will look like

```
(?m)^\h*edit \d+(?:(?!^\h*edit)[\s\S])*?service ("ALL")[\s\S]*?\R\h*next$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lvws2F/2)

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `edit \d+`  - `edit`, space and 1+ digits
- `(?:(?!^\h*edit)[\s\S])*?` - any text not overflowing `edit` that is at the start of a line optionally preceded with 0+ horizontal whitespaces up to the first...
- `service ("ALL")` - `service "ALL"` substring (`"ALL"` is captured into Group 1)
- `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\R` - a line break
- `\h*`  - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `next` -  a literal substring
- `$` - end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that your regex can be simplified to:

```
(edit[\s\S]*?service ("ALL")[\s\S]*?next)
```

Now, regarding your question - the reason it does that is because when you have the

```
"ALL2"
```

in the text, there is now only ONE occurrence of

```
"ALL"
```

in the entire text. Your regex pattern searches specifically for "ALL" (where there is no 2 between the L and the second double-quote)

Comment: Hey, thank you for trying to help me. Sadly your regex does not match anything in my case since there is multiple lines.

Comment: Ah, that's because I tried simplifying the regex. The "." in my regex wasn't matching newlines. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this

```
edit 1035
    set schedule "always"
    set service "ALL2"
    set utm-status enable
next
edit 103
    set schedule "always"
    set service "ALL"
    set utm-status enable
next
```

also match your regex. It starts with

`edit`

then you have a bunch of chars (as less as possible) until your next `service "ALL"`

```
 1035
    set schedule "always"
    set service "ALL2"
    set utm-status enable
next
edit 103
    set schedule "always"
    set
```

Now you have an occurrence of

`service "ALL"`

and then you have another bunch of chars until `next`

```
    set utm-status enable
next
```

So, your regex should be working fine, the whole text matches the first capturing group (1 time), and the words `service "ALL"` matches the second.

[@Marathon55 pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782045/why-is-my-regex-greedy/47785962#47785962) that this regex can be simplified with

`(edit.*?service ("ALL").*?next)`

`[\s\S]` matches any char like `.` does,

`{0,}?` matches any quantity of them (ungreedy) like `*?` does

but in fact, `.` matches all chars except for line terminators, so the regex doesn't match anything due to endlines.